# Searching SQL data fails

Tags: php, sql

Im trying to view an tuple of data from SQL input by search query, however, the result showing an extract of php code instead.

The result shown in html page is:

```
"; } } else { echo "Not Found!!!"."
"; } mysql_close(); ?>
```

I need help to to see where has gone wrong. Below is the SQL code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Booking Results</title>
</head>

<BODY>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<blockquote>
  <p>
<!--  <img src='search.jpg' width=50px height=50px> //-->
  <h2>Search Booking Result</h2>
<?php 
/* connect to my sql */
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
if (!$con)
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database", $con);


/* retrieve all variables  */
$keyword = @$_POST["Activity"];
$searchin = @$_POST["searchin"];


/* execute query  */
$sql="select * from sportscomplex where $searchin LIKE '%$keyword%'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($num != 0)
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultActivity))
    {
        echo $row['Activity']." ".$row['Venue']." ".$row['Hall']." ".$row['Day']
             ." ".$row['Status']." ".$row['Date']."<br>";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Not Found!!!"."<br>";
}
mysql_close();
?>

</blockquote>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the name of your file? It should be named something.php not something.html. Also, make sure you have php installed on your system.

Comment: It looks like it ends when you do "<br>"   now, is this the exact code, or just what is rendered?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection and uses deprecated MySQL code functions. Would advise moving to MySQLi or PDO. Would change your echo like so: `echo "{$row['Activity']} {$row['Venue']} {$row['Hall']} {$row['Day']} {$row['Status']} {$row['Date']}<br />";`